# PHP add record error

Tags: php

I am getting an error with the code below. I am trying to add records to my database and this keeps coming up. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO DEADSPIN_113222561 (FIRST_NAME,USERNAME,PASS_WORD,PASS_WORD2 ) VALUES ('".$FIRST_NAME."','".$USERNAME."''".$PASS_WORD."','".$PASS_WORD_2."',)";
$stmt = oci_parse($cnt, $sql);
oci_execute($stmt,OCI_DEFAULT);
print "Welcome ";
echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['USERNAME']);
```

Error:

> Warning: oci_execute() [function.oci-execute]: ORA-00936: missing expression in 
>       c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\MBSEBus\113222561\Scripts\IS6116 Project\addrecord.php on line 29

Comment: What's on addrecord.php on line 29?

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO DEADSPIN_113222561 (FIRST_NAME,USERNAME,PASS_WORD,PASS_WORD2 ) 
  VALUES ('".$FIRST_NAME."','".$USERNAME."''".$PASS_WORD."','".$PASS_WORD_2."',)";
    
$stmt = oci_parse($cnt, $sql);

Comment: The code above in the question is line 29.

Comment: you missed a comma between $username and $pass_word
      '".$USERNAME."' , '".$PASS_WORD."'   and  comma before  parenthesis not have to go there.

Comment: Thanks I just tried that but still getting the same error.

Comment: yes the error is stil the same because of you have a `,` more at the end of the query before `)`

Comment: Hi @user3460896. Please get into the habit of updating your question rather than adding updates to comments - as well as being more readable, it avoids readers needing to wade through lots of comments to see the state of a question. See my edit just now. Also: don't forget to accept/upvote answers that were useful to you!

Answer (score 1):

You miss a `,` between `$USERNAME` and `$PASS_WORD`. There is also a stray `,` before the closing `)` at the end of the `$sql`.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO DEADSPIN_113222561 (FIRST_NAME,USERNAME,PASS_WORD,PASS_WORD2 ) VALUES ('".$FIRST_NAME."','".$USERNAME."''".$PASS_WORD."','".$PASS_WORD_2."',)";
$stmt = oci_parse($cnt, $sql);
```

Should be:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO DEADSPIN_113222561 (FIRST_NAME,USERNAME,PASS_WORD,PASS_WORD2 ) VALUES ('".$FIRST_NAME."','".$USERNAME."','".$PASS_WORD."','".$PASS_WORD_2."')"; 
$stmt = oci_parse($cnt, $sql);
```

Comment: there is also a comma more at the end of the query

Comment: Can you mark the answer as accepted then please? It's the green tick below the voting numbers. @user3460896

Answer (score 0):

Your query is invalid, try this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO DEADSPIN_113222561 (FIRST_NAME,USERNAME,PASS_WORD,PASS_WORD2 ) VALUES ('".$FIRST_NAME."','".$USERNAME."','".$PASS_WORD."','".$PASS_WORD_2."')";
$stmt = oci_parse($cnt, $sql);
```

You were missing a comma between two values, and there was a comma more at the end of the query.

Answer (score -1):

Put a comma between `$username . '", "' . $password.`